# Оставить фокус в текущем окне при открытии новой вкладки

Tags: jquery

Приветствую. Слабо разбираюсь в jQuery. Может кто-то подсказать код для открытия ссылки в новой вкладке, но при этом чтобы фокус остался в текущей вкладке? То есть чтобы юзер не перенаправлялся автоматом в новую вкладку, а оставался в текущей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(){
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "http://ya.ru/";
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
      a.dispatchEvent(evt);
      return false;
  }
```

[Источник](https://toster.ru/q/160497)

Хотя я лично против, чтобы страница за меня решала, где открыть ссылку.

Comment: Извиняюсь за корявую верстку — с мобилы пишу